# fetch records with its pivot table by laravel belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

I have categories and menu table.
Each menu has many categories
and each category has many menus.
I have a `category_menu` pivot table, and now
I want to fetch all menu records with its categories some thing like that.

Model:

```
class menu extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class homeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Menu $menu, Category $category)
    {
        $this->menu     = $menu;
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['categories'] = $this->category->all();
        $data['menus']      = $this->menu->all()->categories;
        return view('home', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can you reword that, I can't tell what your question is from that.

Comment: i got the answer already thanks , but my question was i want a list of menus table joined with its categories table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i got the answer with a lucky try
it's

```
$this->menu->with('categories')->get();
```

to any one gets into this issue